# Auto upload all my videos to Youtube

Tags: youtube, uploads

I would really like to upload my 4K videos from my Nexus 5X to youtube. I don't want to take any manual steps.

So everytime I shoot a video, I want it sent to youtube without any manual intervention.

How can I achieve this? Tips greatly appreciated.

I upload all my videos to Google Photos, but they are limited to 1080p ...

Comment: Ditto.  One of my phones is the same model too.  Auto-upload to youtube would be excellent for backup since youtube charges nothing per upload.   And it would make sharing much easier.  +1 for this question!

Comment: On a quick investigation on "how would I build this" one issue it seems is that youtube data API has limits per application. So if I were to build this and release it in play store - it'd quickly get throttled by google.

I wonder if there is a way to pretend being the youtube app (add patch to ReVanced?)

Alternatively people can supply their own app keys, which seems involved on the user side 

Comment: https://github.com/porjo/youtubeuploader an example cli automation tool that does this